# Can we have non public constants in BuildConfig?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am writing a library for Android and wanted it to use the constants in the BuildConfig exclusively - so the lib's client, so to speak, won't see them easily.

So, what I would like to achieve is instead of the public constant like this:

```
package my.lib;

public final class BuildConfig {
    public static final boolean FOO = false; 
}
```

it would rather generate a constant with no access modifier that would make the stuff visible in the package of my lib rather:

```
package my.lib;

public final class BuildConfig {
    static final boolean FOO = false; 
}
```

Is it possible to achieve somehow?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the `generate()` method from `BuildConfigGenerator` class:

```
/**
 * Generates the BuildConfig class.
 */
public void generate() throws IOException {
    File pkgFolder = getFolderPath();
    if (!pkgFolder.isDirectory()) {
        if (!pkgFolder.mkdirs()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create " + pkgFolder.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    File buildConfigJava = new File(pkgFolder, BUILD_CONFIG_NAME);
    FileWriter out = new FileWriter(buildConfigJava);
    JavaWriter writer = new JavaWriter(out);
    Set<Modifier> publicFinal = EnumSet.of(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.FINAL);
    Set<Modifier> publicFinalStatic = EnumSet.of(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.FINAL, Modifier.STATIC);
    writer.emitJavadoc("Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY")
            .emitPackage(mBuildConfigPackageName)
            .beginType("BuildConfig", "class", publicFinal);
    for (ClassField field : mFields) {
        writer.emitField(
                field.getType(),
                field.getName(),
                publicFinalStatic,
                field.getValue());
    }
    for (Object item : mItems) {
        if (item instanceof ClassField) {
            ClassField field = (ClassField)item;
            writer.emitField(
                    field.getType(),
                    field.getName(),
                    publicFinalStatic,
                    field.getValue());
        } else if (item instanceof String) {
            writer.emitSingleLineComment((String) item);
        }
    }
    writer.endType();
    out.close();
}
```

}

So this is impossible because `BuildConfigGenerator` creates only  `public final` modifiers

```
Set<Modifier> publicFinal = EnumSet.of(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.FINAL);

writer.emitJavadoc("Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY")
            .emitPackage(mBuildConfigPackageName)
            .beginType("BuildConfig", "class", publicFinal);
```

and does not give you the option to choose)